# modify string if specific regex matches

Tags: php, regex, string, split

Working in PHP, I have the following mock string.

```
"width 40cm height 70cm"
```

If the string does not contain a colon and does have a space followed by a number, I want to add a colon before that space.

The end result I'm looking for is:

```
"width: 40cm height: 70cm"
```

I tried a bunch of ways with regex and splitting the string at the match to add the colon, but it was removing the match string. Here is my attempt.

```
    if(strpos($s, ':') === false) {
        $array = preg_split('/([0-9])/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $array[0] = trim($array[0]) . ':';
        $s = implode('', $array);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
(\w+)(?=\s+\d)
     <------->
     Lookahead to match
     space followed by 
     digits
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI0vC1/3)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/(\\w+)(?=\\s+\\d)/m"; 
$str = "width 40cm height 70cm\nwidth: 40cm height 70cm"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, "$1:", $str);
print_r($result);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/PMpItt)**

Comment: No need to put a negative lookahead here: `(?!:)\s`, a white-space can't be a colon.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are right..my fault..i wrote the lookahead part in starting and then added the `\w` part and messed it up..

Answer (score 1):

The following regex might work for you:

```
/(?<!:)(?= \d)/g
```

With replacement: `:`

```
$output = preg_replace('/(?<!:)(?= \d)/', ':', $input);
```

It matches a position that is followed before space and digit `(?= \d)` and not preceded by a colon `(?<!:)`. That's why the replacement group can be a colon only.

This is called [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Here be both use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) `(?=...)` and a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind): `(?<!...)`.

https://www.regex101.com/r/oH7cI3/1

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds:

```
(?<=[a-z]) # a-z behind
\          # a space
(?=\d)     # a digit ahead
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kO9mM8/1) and replace the occurences with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="width: 40cm height: 70cm";
```

`$temp=exploade(" ",$string);`

`foreach($temp as $value){`

```
if(strstr($value,'width') && strstr($value,'height')){
    $new_temp[]=$value.":";
}else{
    $new_temp[]=$value;
}
```

}
`$new_string=implode(" ", $new_temp);`